# Incompatible version of OpenSSL on android in qt quick application

Tags: android, c++, qt, ssl

I have a qt quick application that run with no error on `Windows` and `Android` . But when I use `QNetworkAccessManager` to make GET request it have no error on windows but have below error on Android

```
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_init_ssl
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_init_crypto
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve ASN1_STRING_get0_data
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_PKEY_base_id
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve RSA_bits
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_new_null
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_push
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_free
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_num
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_pop_free
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_sk_value
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve DH_get0_pqg
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_ciphersuites
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_use_session_callback
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_client_random
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_SESSION_get_master_key
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_client_method
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLS_server_method
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get0_chain
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_getm_notBefore
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_getm_notAfter
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_get_version
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_set_ex_data
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_get_ex_data
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_free
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OpenSSL_version_num
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve OpenSSL_version
W ShakhehNabat: qt.network.ssl: Incompatible version of OpenSSL
```

I run the below code and

```
    qWarning()<<"QSslSocket build version =>"<<QSslSocket::sslLibraryBuildVersionString();
    qWarning()<<"QSslSocket version =>"<<QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString();
    qWarning()<<"QSslSocket supportsSsl =>"<<QSslSocket::supportsSsl();
```

and Here is **output on Windows**

```
QSslSocket build version => "OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019"
QSslSocket version => "OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019"
QSslSocket supportsSsl => true
```

and Here is **output on Android**

```
W ShakhehNabat: QSslSocket version => ""
W ShakhehNabat: QSslSocket supportsSsl => false
W ShakhehNabat: QSslSocket build version => "OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019"
```

I have Installed Qt 5.12.5 MSVC2017 64bit and Qt 5.12.5 for Android ARMv7,But I have just two folder **Win_x64** and **Win_x86** in path ( `C:\Qt\Tools\OpenSSL` )

**Edit**

When I make request I will get this error

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
```

Do I need to do some initialization for ssl socket? should I add **pem** file to my application?

Comment: You'll have to package OpenSSL for Android, see https://github.com/KDAB/android_openssl

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I don't know how to add this package to my project,I edited my question